# Python Anaconda package built and installed, but cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, packaging, conda

I built a `python3` package called `gender_univ` using the Anaconda `conda build` command. I uploaded the package to the Anaconda cloud and then installed it into my `conda` environment. Though the package shows up in the list of installed packages when I type `conda list`, whenever I try to access the package using `import gender_univ` I get the error `no module named gender_univ`.

I want to understand why I can't seem to import a package that is apparently installed in my conda virtual environment? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would check that you are using the correct python (i.e. `which python` and confirm that it is the python in your conda environment). Next, you can check if your package is in the site-packages directory of that same python.

The most likely thing, I'd bet, is that the conda package doesn't include everything correctly.  Are you sure that you have a build.sh (or bld.bat if you are on windows) and a setup.py?  Did you try expanding your built conda package and looking for your python classes in there?

If you expand your built conda package, probably something like `gender_univ-VERSION-py35_0.tar.bz2`, you should see a `lib/python3.5/site-packages/gender_univ` directory (i.e. python package).  Do you?  If not, then the failure is with your building.

Comment: Ahh this is good. Yeah, I checked the site-packages directory and the gender_univ directory is there, but the code is missing. So you are right about the build, which is what I suspected. I just did not know where to look to diagnose the problem. Thanks for your help.